# Why after sending a response, node is still executing further middleware in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

so i have a very basic blog app made in express, and the thing is that when i respond to app.get('/') and render a home page view, the server is still responding to app.get('/:id') that is further in the code.
I didn't call next() in app.get('/'), and from what i know, when i render a view, then the rest of middleware after shouldn't get executed, so why is it executing app.get('/:id')?

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();

// Setting up basic middleware
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views');


// Database things
// ...

// Home page
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    res.render('index')
})


// Get add new blog page
app.get('/add-new', (req, res) => {

    res.render('addblog')
})


// Respond with single blog page
app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {

    const id = req.params.id;
    Blog.findById(id)
        .then(data => res.render('blog', { data }))
})


// 404
app.use('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('404')
})
```

Comment: it could be anything, from an asset to a favicon, in /:id route debug `req.originalUrl`

Comment: `app.get('/:id')` isnt a middleware, its just another route.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand properly what you meant to ask but from what I understood, I think you mean to ask that even if someone calls /123, (Here 123 is the id) the code to be executed should be

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    res.render('index')
})
```

If this is what you mean to ask, then that's not how it's done. Only [www.yoursite.com/](http://www.yoursite.com/) request goes to `app.get('/', (req, res)` and any route having value after [www.yoursite.com/](http://www.yoursite.com/) like [www.yoursite.com/123](http://www.yoursite.com/123) will go to the other route which renders single page. 1 more thing. As you have written that if you didn't call next, rest of the middleware shouldn't execute after render, that is not the case. The entire middleware has to execute unless there is an error or you call the return statement like return res.render or simply return.

Comment: No, that's not what i meant. When i go to 'mysite.com/', server renders the home page, and that's good, but it then also responds to '/:id' route, and now i see that it  causes error   (CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "favicon.ico" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Blogs"), so should i response to '/favicon.ico' with something, or should do something else to prevent that error?

Comment: @thekensiwo Try using app.get('/abcd':_id) instead of app.get('/:id') and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

your 404 Route should be :

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
   res.render('404');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

every middelware you have to return something in you case:

```
return res.render('the-page')
```

without return it will not work